# Parse whole list in querydict dictionary in Django

Tags: javascript, django, parsing, dictionary, django-templates

I have a querydict which I pass to Django's template. This querydict may look like this:

`<QueryDict: {u'VAR1': [u'val1', u'val2', u'val3'], u'VAR2': u'val4', u'VAR3': [u'val5'], u'VAR4': []}>`

- The dictionary can be larger, shorter, but it will always contain a field which has a list inside, and this list can be empty also.
- In the previous example it can be seen "key-value" pair containing a list ("VAR1-val1_2_3") a "key-value" pair containing an empty list ("VAR4-[]") a "key-value" pair containing a list with one item ("VAR3-val5") and a "key-value" pair containing a string ("VAR2-val4")
- In the template I know the key names of all entries in the querydict

**I would like to parse the whole list from the querydict into a Javascript variable, so it looks like this:**

`var trial = ['val1', 'val2', 'val3']` for key "VAR1"

or

`var trial = ['val5']` for key "VAR3"

or

`var trial = []` for key "VAR4"

depending on which is the original list on the dictionary

I have tried many options but I haven't succeeded, any help please?

Comment: Please share me the django query that you wrote for getting Querydict?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't pass the querydict directly to the template. Convert it to a JSON string instead:

```
data = json.dumps(dict(my_querydict))
```

(You need to convert it to dict first, to bypass the querydict's special handling of multi-value keys.)

Now your JS can access it in your template:

```
var data = {{ data|safe }};
var var1 = data.var1;
```